Error in HomeController: InvalidOperationException:
I'm currently running into this error in the build of my project. I am trying to do a detailed search, where users can search based off of location and date. When I run it, though, I get the following:
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable2[Final_Project.Models.FlightRoute,System.Int32]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[Final_Project.Models.Flight]'.
My current display result functions look like this:
    public IActionResult DisplaySearchResults(SearchViewModel svm)
    {
        //set up initial query
        var query = from fr in _context.FlightRoutes
                    select fr;

        //check for criteria 1:
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(svm.OriginCity) == false)
        {
            query = query.Where(fr => fr.OriginCity.Contains(svm.OriginCity));
        }
        //check for criteria 2:
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(svm.DestinationCity) == false)
        {
            query = query.Where(f => f.DestinationCity.Contains(svm.DestinationCity));
        }
        List<FlightRoute> SelectedFlights = query.Include(fr => fr.Flights).ToList();
        ViewBag.SelectedFlights = SelectedFlights.Count();
        ViewBag.AllCities = _context.Flights.Count();
        return View("Index", SelectedFlights.OrderBy(s => s.FlightRouteID));
    }

    public IActionResult DisplaySearchResult(SearchViewModel svm)
    {
        //set up initial query
        var query = from f in _context.Flights
                        select f;

        //check for release date:
        if (svm.DeptDate != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(f => f.DepartureDate >= svm.DeptDate);
        }

        if (svm.ReturnDate != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(f => f.ArrivalDate >= svm.ReturnDate);
        }


        List<Flight> SelectedFlights = query.Include(fr => fr.FlightID).ToList();
        ViewBag.SelectedFlights = SelectedFlights.Count();
        ViewBag.AllCities = _context.Flights.Count();
        return View("Index", SelectedFlights.OrderBy(s => s.FlightID));

    }

These are in the HomeController. I don't have any reference tags in the top of my controller.
